# Open graph single image but showing multiple

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph

We are using the og:image property to supply facebook with the correct image, but in some instances it get's more images which it parses from the DOM. eg:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Ffunda.nl%2Fkoop%2Futrecht%2Fappartement-48611144-breedstraat-122%2F&t=Woning+te+koop%3A+Breedstraat+122%2C+Utrecht

Only the first image should be shown there. If you look in the debugger it looks fine:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.funda.nl%2Fkoop%2Futrecht%2Fappartement-48611144-breedstraat-122%2F

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this issue in a site I maintain.
It appears that bloody Facebook changed again things without notifying anything to developers..
Image for og:image must be now at least 200x200px.
If it is smaller, than facebook will take other images that it parses from the same URL, even if these images have nothing to do as leading image for that URL.
Just take care that og:image is big enough and it will be ok.
* Notice that even after you change it, it may appear wrong for some time, if the URL is already cached  in FB. To solve it immediately, just pass again the URL to the FB debugger.